# blueimp-gallery rotating big picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blueimp

I use blueimp-gallery with the bootstrap plugin and all portrait pictures are 90° rotate on left. Is this a bug from blueimp or navigator?

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Gallery -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-use-bootstrap-modal="false">
    <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <!-- Controls for the borderless lightbox -->
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
    <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
    <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body next"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                        Previous
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
                        Next
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="links" class="hidden">
    {% for image in images %}
    <a href="{{ image.image.url }}" title="{{ image.name }}" data-gallery>
        <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="{{ image.name }}">
    </a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$("#diapBtn").on('click', function(e){
    links = $('#links a');
    blueimp.Gallery(links, {useBootstrapModal: false});
});
```

The blueimp-gallery documentation doesn't talk about flip or rotation of pictures.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be asked of the program's authors